# ProGuard with duplicate jar libraries for modules in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, module, android-studio, proguard, libraries

I've got an Android project in IntelliJ and I can't seem to get ProGuard to work. The project is divided in several **modules** since some of them are used in other apps. The app structure is as follows:

- **Main Module** - normal Android App with some Activities

  - **libs/viewpageindicator** - library module (not a jar)
  - **libs/slidingmenu** - library module (not a jar)
- **Network Module** - a library project for network communication.

Now the problem is that all of those module depend on the same **external** libraries - such as the `android support library` or `spring`.
For example, the **Main Module** and the **Network Module** both need the `libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar` library. IntelliJ manages all the project libraries nice and tight, so you can just assign them to the different projects - this way the app compiles without any problems.

However once you compile the app with ProGuard it takes the libraries as input and throws errors:

`Information:ProGuard: [main] Reading program jar [intellij/generated/proguard_input1846333276098786347.jar]`
`Information:ProGuard: [main] Reading program jar [/libs/android-support-v4.jar]`
`Information:ProGuard: [main] Reading program jar [/libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar]`
`Information:ProGuard: [main] Reading library jar [android-sdk/platforms/android-16/android.jar]`

...

`Error:ProGuard: [main] Warning: android.support.v4.media.TransportMediatorJellybeanMR2: can't find superclass or interface android.media.RemoteControlClient$OnGetPlaybackPositionListener`
...

Now I've read the official [documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass) and I've tried both 1,2 and 3 without any success. 
Simply ignoring the libraries doesn't work:
`-dontwarn android.support.**`
`-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }`
`-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }`

the app is obfuscated but crashes instantly:

`E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: package.name, PID: 7335
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
            at a.b.a.d.am.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at a.d.b.b.a.a.<init>(Unknown Source)`

Specifying the libraries as `-libraryjars` also doesn't work:

`-libraryjars libs/android-support-v4.jar`

This just adds the library to the libraries list ... and now the library is added twice, once as injar and once as a libraryjar. So there are duplicate classes errors. I've tried all sorts of combinations with injars / library jars, I even tried moving the jars to the SDK sources.

Any idea on how to manage ProGuard in a project with several Modules? Perhaps excluding some of the jars? It seems they are being added twice by IntelliJ, unfortunately it seems I can't edit the all the input parameters supplied by IntelliJ.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.